# mod_rewrite to find missing /img/foo.jpg in /img/f/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a folder of images which is reaching a critical mass after a few years.

I want to move images into alphabetical folders, so that `/img/foo.jpg` goes into `/img/f/foo.jpg` and `/img/bar.jpg` goes into `/img/b/bar.jpg` and so on.

In order to make the transition smooth, and to allow the manual uploaders to put stuff into the top level, I'd like to use mod_rewrite to do this:

- if `/img/foo.jpg` exists, serve it
  up,
- if not look for it in
  `/img/f/foo.jpg`

thanks for any suggestions.

For the record, no, I don't think we need to go `/img/f/fo/foo.jpg` just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?img/(.)(.*)$ /img/$1/$1$2
```